# Selenium, pythons web scraping

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from HTML table.
Successfully counted the row but when I'm printing it keeps repeating the row.
Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in code?
Thanks.

```py
#counting length of row
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/fieldset/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr'))
time.sleep(2)
print(rows)

for r in range(rows):
    value=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/fieldset/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]')
    print(value.text)


#Output:
18 #no of rows
Start of legal relation2/7/2018 #1st row
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
Start of legal relation2/7/2018
sample test case successfully completed
```

Comment: Website url pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a URL you have supplied, it's difficult to say why. However, the first `tr` element would be `[1]`, so I think your `range` function should be `range(1, rows + 1)`. And the way you are going about this seems very indirect since your first query seems to have retrieved all the elements you are looking for. So why not just the following?

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/fieldset/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr')
#time.sleep(2) # what does this accomplish?
print(len(elements))

text_list = [element.text for element in elements] # list of strings
```

Comment: Thank youuuu soooo much, whoever you are. it is my first time using selenium and i was trying to correct the mistake from yesterday continuously, now it works from the code you provided. 
Why i didnt provide the URL is because it is my university's management system and you need to provide student id and password.

Thanks again

Comment: If your range function is as you stated, your first `find_element_by_xpath` would have as an argument '/html/body/form/fieldset/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[0]' and that should have thrown a NoSuchElement exception, so I don't know how you got any results.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I save elements in a string?
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "save elements in a string". You are interested in the text within the `tr` elements rather than the elements themselves, right? These are each strings. Do you want a list of strings or all the strings joined together in one string with a separator? Or something totally different? Or is my assumption as to what you want totally wrong?

Comment: yes, i want those elements to covert in a string or they can be a list. 
Why i want this is because i want to save all those elements in a word file. so for that i need to save them as a string/list.
did you understand?

Comment: I have updated the answer to instead create a list of strings. Does that help? The code that was there before (i.e. with a print statement), could have been slightly changed to print each line to an open file by specifying the `file=` keyword argument.